# Pandas Dataframe Conditions and manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm stuck on a part of project i'm working on , i have a Dataframe with multiple columns , i would like to fill a column with the value of an other column based on 2 conditions.

below i have tried to give an example of my Dataframe : i would like to get the last day of the month being added to the Col [ ValuedteTo ] which is based on the date in Col [ Value Dte ] if Col [ Market ] value is equal to EEX or ICE ( or simply if the Col [ ValuedteTo ] is empty then adding the date )

| Lot | Contract | Value Dte | ValuedteTo | Market |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -10 | 2024-03 | 2024-03-01 |  | EEX |
| 10 | 2024-05 | 2024-05-01 |  | ICE |
| -25 | 2024-10 | 2024-10-01 |  | ICE |
| 250 | 2024-11 | 2024-11-01 | 2024-11-10 | OTC |
| 30 | 2024-02 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-02 | OTC |
| -10 | 2024-01 | 2024-01-01 |  | EEX |
| -50 | 2024-09 | 2024-09-01 | 2024-09-30 | OTC |
| -80 | 2024-10 | 2024-10-01 |  | EEX |

i have tried to first create a function to get the last day of a month based ona specific date
and then try to use that with the following line of code.
however no success

```
df['valueDate_To_'] = df.apply(lambda x: last_day_of_month(df['valueDate_From_'])if (x['market'] == 'EEX' or x['market'] == 'ICE') else x['valueDate_To_'], axis = 1)
```

```
def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    # The day 28 exists in every month. 4 days later, it's always next month
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    # subtracting the number of the current day brings us back one month
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right. This is the solution:

Next time kindly post a minimum reproduction of your code:

Let us say that you have a data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Value_Dte'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Value_Dte'])
df['ValuedteTo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ValuedteTo'], errors='coerce')
```

The code which you have given doesn't extract the date from datetime object and I have modified this.

```
def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + timedelta(days=4)
    return (next_month - timedelta(days=next_month.day)).date()


def fill_valuedteto(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['ValuedteTo']) and row['Market'] in ['EEX', 'ICE']:
        return last_day_of_month(row['Value_Dte'])
    else:
        return row['ValuedteTo']

df['ValuedteTo'] = df.apply(fill_valuedteto, axis=1)
```

This should be it or if you want it with your snippet

```
df['valueDate_To_'] = df.apply(lambda x: last_day_of_month(x['ValuedteTo']) if (x['Market'] == 'EEX' or x['Market'] == 'ICE') else x['ValuedteTo'], axis=1)
```

Kindly change the col names as you did not provide a reproducible example to create a dataframe.

Comment: Hello , yes it working great thank you very much for your help - this was my first post so i wasnt sure how detailed i had to be etc. however for next time i'll try to put more of my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pd.offsets.MonthEnd() to get the month end and a condition to replace only the values who are missing or are equal to either EEX or ICE.

```
df['Value Dte'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Value Dte'])
df['ValuedteTo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ValuedteTo'], errors='coerce')

cond = (df['ValuedteTo'].isna()) | df['Market'].isin(['EEX ', 'ICE'])
df.loc[cond, 'ValuedteTo'] = df.loc[cond, 'Value Dte'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
```

This is the end result.

| Lot | Contract | Value Dte | ValuedteTo | Market |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -10 | 2024-03 | 2024-03-01 | 2024-03-31 | EEX |
| 10 | 2024-05 | 2024-05-01 | 2024-05-31 | ICE |
| -25 | 2024-10 | 2024-10-01 | 2024-10-31 | ICE |
| 250 | 2024-11 | 2024-11-01 | 2024-11-10 | OTC |
| 30 | 2024-02 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-02 | OTC |
| -10 | 2024-01 | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-31 | EEX |
| -50 | 2024-09 | 2024-09-01 | 2024-09-30 | OTC |
| -80 | 2024-10 | 2024-10-01 | 2024-10-31 | EEX |

Comment: Thank you Sir - this one works as well , i'll just try which one will be the quicker one to run my code and also in term of reducing the number of line of my code . this seems to be a really good alternative.